# Imagem não carrega no e-mail ao ser disparada pela aplicação

Tags: html, email

Quando o administrador realizar o cadastro de um vendedor é disparado um e-mail automático para o e-mail fornecido "E-mail de boas vindas;".

Estou com problema quando o vendedor recebe o mesmo, a logo da empresa não é exibida conforme a imagem.

```
<img src="~/images/logo-email.png" alt="" width="300" height="118" />
```

Já tentei colocar `../` ou `~/` e mesmo assim a imagem não é carregada quando o vendedor recebe o mesmo.

Se eu abrir esse arquivo html pela pasta a logo exibe normalmente, porem quando é enviado o e-mail a pessoa que recebe não consegue visualizar a logo no topo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Thiago, acredito que seja melhor você colocar o caminho inteiro para acessar a foto, exemplo: `http://site.com/images/logo-email.png`

Comment: É pq a imagem não existe no caminho especificado, né. Ou você deixa a imagem inteira embutida no e-mail ou aponta pra um caminho """global""".

Comment: Precisa inserir a URL completa da imagem, e também alguns servidores não permitem a exibição de imagem, pedindo para que o usuário desbloqueie, ou que a origem esteja adicionada na lista de e-mails liberados, tem duas situações para analisar.

Comment: Show rapaziada, deu certo aqui!!